# play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: id to load is required for loading

Tags: java, playframework, illegalargumentexception

I'm getting error at "User.findById(user_id)" not frequently but some times, I don't know why. What causes this error?

Note : I'm using Play version 1.2.3

Thanks.

Function where throws exception;

```
public static void getMemberProfile(Long user _id){
       User sessionUser = getUser();
        User user = User.findById(user_id);
```

Error message ;

```
2012-02-12T13:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-02-12T13:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]: Execution exception (In /app/controllers/UserApi.java around line 470)
2012-02-12T13:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]: IllegalArgumentException occured : id to load is required for loading
2012-02-12T13:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-02-12T13:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]: play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: id to load is required for loading
2012-02-12T13:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:229)
2012-02-12T13:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
2012-02-12T13:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id to load is required for loading
2012-02-12T13:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.hibernate.event.LoadEvent.<init>(LoadEvent.java:89)
2012-02-12T13:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.hibernate.event.LoadEvent.<init>(LoadEvent.java:61)
2012-02-12T13:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1002)
2012-02-12T13:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:998)
2012-02-12T13:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:614)
2012-02-12T13:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:589)
2012-02-12T13:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.db.jpa.JPQL.findById(JPQL.java:34)
2012-02-12T13:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   at models.User.findById(User.java)
2012-02-12T13:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   at controllers.UserApi.getMemberProfile(UserApi.java:470)
2012-02-12T13:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:546)
2012-02-12T13:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:500)
2012-02-12T13:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:476)
2012-02-12T13:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:471)
2012-02-12T13:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:159)
```

Comment: I don't know Play, so just guessing, but could it be that the `user_id` is null (since you're using a Long-object, not a long-primitive)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get this exception because you pass a null `user_id` to the method.

It's easily findable by

- reading the error message
- reading the source code of `org.hibernate.event.LoadEvent`

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you check the routes file

I am also a beginner but I learned that from my senior

```
---------------
# Import CRUD routes
*      /admin              module:crud
---------------
```

must be above

```
# Catch all
*       /{controller}/{action}                  {controller}.{action}
```

If you put that under this it's not gonna work

shortly

```
# Catch all
*       /{controller}/{action}                  {controller}.{action}
```

MUST be the last line.